# iOS OpenGLES 2.0 blending differences between iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am implementing normal UIKit-like blending using textures with transparency in OpenGLES 2.

On iOS 9.3.5 blending works correct on iPad mini for textures with premultiplied alpha and following blend function:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

On iOS 10.3.1 blending works correct on iPad Air for textures with non-premultiplied alpha and the same blend function.

Textures are loaded via this line:

```
[glkTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path 
         options: @{ GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication : @NO /* @YES here for iOS 9 */ }
        queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
        completionHandler:^(GLKTextureInfo * _Nullable textureInfo, 
                                   NSError * _Nullable outError) {
                                                                    ...
                                                                 }
```

What can cause such differences in rendering?